# PyDev not showing AT ALL in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, pydev

I tried two PyDev installation methods and I can't get any results so far... it is not shown in my Preference menu. I've already tried:

a) Putting the PyDev UNZIPPED and ZIPPED files in the dropins folder.
b) Updating via "Help" menu.

*I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5 (I think it's Mt. Lion).
*Eclipse Juno.
*Copied both PyDev 3.0 and 2.7.6
*I've installed JDK 7 and 8...using 7.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Mac is not picking up Java 7 properly when you start Eclipse on Mac OS (even after you installed it).

There's a section on http://pydev.org/download.html (PyDev does not appear after install!) which explains how to fix that.